# Is there a way to manually enter transforms in RViz between two cameras?

Tags: kinect, rviz, ros-hydro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two Kinects and want to merge the point clouds from each one into a single scene in Rviz.  However, from what I have seen RViz can only handle one camera at a time.  How might I add more than one camera and how once I have the extrinsic calibrations, could I manually enter the transform between them?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/130536/is-there-a-way-to-manually-enter-transforms-in-rviz-between-two-cameras?/) by [Athoesen](https://answers.ros.org/users/8296/athoesen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 429 on 2014-02-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rviz can handle multiple cameras, provided they are all properly linked by a tf tree. If you want to manually calibrate two cameras against each other, you could write a small node with a tf TransformBroadcaster and modify the transform it publishes via some kind of GUI. This way, you could adjust the relative camera positions in real-time. Using a interactive marker for this would result in a system that is pretty intuitive to use. Not sure there´s an implementation of this directly available (probably yes, but I´m not aware of it).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-02-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1